# Format of training data in CSV type for encog 3.0 and using it

Tags: neural-network, encog

I wonder that how can I make a csv file for storing training data in encog. Currently I have 200 features (f) as inputs  and multi outputs (o) (for example author A, B ,C...). So how can organize the CSV file ? Should I look like this?

```
f1, f2, f3 ... f200, o1
f1, f2, f3 ... f200, o2
f1, f2, f3 ... f200, o3
```

Some of my questions are:

- Can o1, o2 and o3 accept String ? (Authors' names).
- Will the format of training csv file and testing cvs file look the same ?
- Is it possible to feed the NN directly with the CSV file ? Or It must be converted to multi dimension array as this examples ? Since I have to 200 features as inputs, this will quite difficult.

> ```
> double XOR_INPUT[][] = [
>         [0,0],
>         [1,0],
>         [0,1],
>         [1,1]
> ];
> ```

- How to normalize the data in the csv file (to -+1 range) by using encog framework ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

No. A neural network operates only with float numbers, preferably 0 to 1 (output) or -1 to 1 (input). For strings, use 1 of n encoding.

So eg. if your outputs are 'a', 'b', 'c', set it to

```
1 0 0       = 'a'
0 1 0       = 'b'
0 0 1       = 'c'
```

You can also add a null class if necessary, for no result found.
You can read the data from csv, but encog is looking for everything in a 2d double array (or more correctly an 'array of arrays').
To simplify things, start with say 10 features.

Normalization is done per feature. So for each feature, the formula for normalization for a datapoint a is:

`((a - min) / range) + 1`

Where `range = max - min` of that feature.

So all input datapoints should be in the range -1 to 1.

Maybe post a real example of the data, that might give a better impression of what you need to do.